# Using argparse, how can I process a "chdir" argument before fromfile expansion?

Tags: python, argparse, fromfile

I want to support a sub-command CLI model, like used by `git` The particular bit I'm having trouble with is the "change directory" option. Like `git`, I want a `-C DIR` option which will have the program change to the specified directory before doing the sub-command. Not really a problem, using sub-parsers, **BUT** I also want to use the `argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')` mechanism *after* the `-C DIR` argument is applied during parsing.

Here's the rub: `fromfile` argument expansion is performed by `argparse` *before all other argument processing.* Thus, any such `fromfile` arguments must either use absolute paths, or paths relative to the CWD at time the parser is invoked. I *don't* want absolute paths; I *"need"* to use `fromfile` paths that are *relative to the `-C DIR` option.* I wrote my own `class ChdirAction(argparse.Action)` to do the obvious. It worked fine, but since `fromfile` arguments were already expanded, it didn't give me what I want. (After discovering this *not-what-I-want* behavior, I looked at `python3.5/argparse.py` and found the same frustration embedded in cold, hard, unforgiving code.)

Here's a directory diagram that might help explain what I want:

```
/ foo / aaa / iii / arg.txt
      |     |
      |     + jjj / arg.txt
      |     |
      |     + arg.txt
      |
      + bbb / iii / arg.txt
            |
            + jjj / arg.txt
```

Consider when the CWD is either `aaa` or `bbb` at the time command line arguments are parsed. If I run with something like `prog -C ./iii @arg.txt`
I want the parser to expand `@arg.txt` with arguments from `/foo/aaa/iii/arg.txt`.  What actually happens is that `fromfile` expands from the contents of `/foo/aaa/arg.txt`. When CWD is `/foo/aaa` this is the "wrong" file; when `/foo/bbb` it raises "error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'arg.txt'"

More generally, `prog -C ./DIR @arg.txt` should expand from `/foo/aaa/DIR/arg.txt` which should work even the `fromfile` has "up-directory" parts, e.g. `prog -C ./iii @../arg.txt` should expand from `/foo/aaa/arg.txt`.

If this behavior can be made to happen, then I could `-C DIR` to any of `{aaa,bbb}/{iii,jjj}` and obtain consitent behaviour from a common command line construction.

As described, my problem isn't much of a problem. If can provide the `-C DIR`, to be realized by an `os.chdir(DIR)` after argument parsing, then I can also construct appropriate `fromfile` arguments. They could be either absolute or relative to the CWD *at parsing* (prior to any `-C DIR` taking effect). This might look like:

`cd /foo/aaa; prog -C ./DIR @arg.txt @./DIR/arg.txt`

I don't like it, but it would be okay. The ***REAL*** problem is that the actual change-directory argument I'm using is more like `-C PATTERN`. In my real problem case, PATTERN could be a simple path (absolute or relative). Or, it might be a glob pattern, or a partial name that has "non-trivial" resolution logic to find the actual directory for `os.chdir(DIR)`. In this case (which I am struggling with), I can't have the invoker of the program resolve the actual location of the `fromfile` path.

Actually, I *could,* but that would put an inappropriate burden on the invoker. AND, when that invoker is an Eclipse launcher, I don't really have the control-flow power necessary to do it. So, it's back to having the program take care of it's own needs; a nicer abstraction, but ***how do I implement it?***

Answer (score 0):

Even as I was fleshing out the question, I came up with an idea. So I tried it out and it's kinda, sorta, okay(ish). I can get a constrained version of what I really want, but it's good enough for me (for now), so I thought I might as well share. It might be good enough for you, too. Even better, it might elicit a true solution from somewhere, *maybe S.Bethard?*

My hack is to do parsing in two phases: the first, is just enough to get the `-C PATTERN` argument by way of `ArgumentParser.parse_known_args(...)` *without enabling the `fromfile` mechanism*. If the result of that first (minimal) parsing yields a directory change argument, then I process it. The program aborts if more than a single `-C PATTERN` was specified, or the PATTERN can't be unambiguously resolved.

Then, I use a completely separate `ArgumentParser` object, configured with the full set of argument specifications that I actually want and parse it *with the `fromfile` mechanism enabled.*

There is some monkey business to get the `--help` argument to work (setting the proper conflict resolution policy, then merely accepting the arg in the first parser just to pass along to the second, which actually has all the "real" argument specs). Also, the first parser should support the same verbose/quiet options that the second one does, honoring their setting and also passing along from first to second parser.

Here's a simplified version of my application-level arg parser method. It doens't support verbose/quiet options at the first parser stage. I've elided the complexity of how a `-C PATTERN` is resolved to an actual directory. Also, I cut out the majority of the second parser's argument specification, leaving just the second parser's `-C PATTERN` argument (needed for `--help` output).

NOTE: Both parsers have a `-C PATTERN` argument. In the `chdirParser` it is meaningful; in the `argParser` it's present only so it will show up in the help output. Something similar should be done for verbose/quiet options - probably not that trixy, but it's not (yet) important to me so I don't mind always reporting a change of directory, even in quiet mode.

```
def cli_args_from_argv():

    import argparse
    import glob
    import os
    import sys

    chdirParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(conflict_handler='resolve')
    chdirParser.add_argument("-C",           dest="chdir_pattern", action="append"    , default=None)
    chdirParser.add_argument("--help", "-h", dest="help",          action="store_true", default=False)

    (partial, remainder) = chdirParser.parse_known_args()

    if partial.help:
        remainder = ['--help']

    elif partial.chdir_pattern:
        if len(partial.chdir_pattern) > 1:
            print(r'Too many -C options - at most one may be given, but received: {!r}'.format(partial.chdir_pattern), file=sys.stderr)
            sys.exit(1)

        pattern  = partial.chdir_pattern[0]
        resolved_dir = pattern
        if os.path.exists(resolved_dir):
            resolved_dir = pattern

        else:

            ### ELIDED: resolution of pattern into an unambiguous and existing directory

            if not resolved_dir:
                print("Failed to resolve -C {!r}".format(pattern), file=sys.stderr)
                sys.exit(1)

        print("Changing to directory: {!r}".format(resolved_dir))
        print("");

        os.chdir(target_dir)


    argParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage="usage: PROG [common-args] SUBCMD [subcmd-args]", fromfile_prefix_chars=':')

    ### ELIDED: a bunches of add_argument(...)

    argParser.add_argument("-C", dest="chdir_spec", action="store", default=None, help="Before anything else, chdir to SPEC", metavar="SPEC")

    return argParser.parse_args(args=remainder)
```

I have a feeling that there's probably a better way... Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `resolve` bit can be replaced with

```
chdirParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
```

and omit the `-h` definition and save.  Let the second parser handle `sys.argv` unchanged (since you are including (but ignoring) the `-C` argument).

That `append` and test for `len(partial.chdir_pattern) > 1` should work if you expect the user to use several `-C dir1 ... -C dir2...` commands.  The alternative to use the default `store` action, which ends up saving the last of those repetitions. Why might the user repeat the `-C`, and why should you care?  Usually we just ignore repetitions.

You might replace

```
print("Failed to resolve -C {!r}".format(pattern), file=sys.stderr)
sys.exit(1)
```

with

```
parser.error("Failed to resolve -C {!r}".format(pattern)')
```

It prints the usage (with only `-C) and does an`sys.exit(2)`.  Not quite the same, but may be close enough.

For the second parser, the `-C` might be simplified (using defaults):

```
argParser.add_argument("-C", "--chdir-spec", help="Before anything else, chdir to SPEC", metavar="SPEC")
```

And use the full `sys.argv`.

```
return argParser.parse_args()
```

Otherwise, using 2 parsers makes sense, since the `fromfile` is present in the changed directory (and you want to ignore any such file in the initial directory).

I thought maybe a `:arg.txt` string the commandline would give problems in the first parser.  But with `parse_known_args` it will just treat it as an unknown positional. But the proof's in the testing.

Comment: I like your refinements and will add them to my own program code - esp. just letting the second parser work with `sys.argv`. That simplifies the invocation of the second parser, and allows me to enhance the first one with verbose/quiet handling without doing anything special to "inject" them back into the `remaining` arguments given to the second parser

Comment: You ask "Why would someone use multiple `-C SPEC` options?" I dunno, but getting more than one indicates a misunderstanding of the CLI usage or a mistake in construction. In either case I want to catch that and force the invoker to clean up their act. The "standard" of ignoring multiple occurances rarely feels right to me, and this is not an exception.

Comment: As for the first parser coping with a `:arg.txt` occurence: Without turning on the `fromfile` mechanism (which I don't), such arguments are, indeed, considered as "ignored unknown positional args" by the first parser. It is already working that way for me. From the testing came out the proof...